# Move an UIImageView around in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm creating an application where I want to let the user move (*not* pan) an UIImageView around by dragging it on the screen. Additionally, I want the user to be able to zoom the UIImageView in and out.

As such I've been using a custom *UIScrollView* that forwards single touches to the 'contentView':

```
@implementation JM_UIScrollView

- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    NSLog(@"Checking for touches: %d", [allTouches count]);

    if ([allTouches count] == 1) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;  
}

@end
```

Along with a custom *UIImageView* that implements *touchesBegan* and *touchesMoved* to determine where to move the UIImageView:

```
@implementation JM_UIImageView
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    if ([allTouches count] == 0)
        return;

    UITouch *firstTouch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex: 0];

    CGPoint touchLoc = [firstTouch locationInView: [self superview]];

    touchOffset= CGPointMake(touchLoc.x-self.center.x,touchLoc.y-self.center.y);
    NSLog(@"Currently at: %3.3f x %3.3f", touchLoc.x, touchLoc.y);

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    if ([allTouches count] == 0)
        return;

    UITouch *firstTouch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex: 0];
    CGPoint touchLoc = [firstTouch locationInView: [self superview]];

    if ([allTouches count] == 1)
    {           
        if ([firstTouch view] == self)
        {

            touchLoc.x -= touchOffset.x;
            touchLoc.y -= touchOffset.y;

            NSLog(@"Moved to: %3.3f x %3.3f", touchLoc.x, touchLoc.y);
            self.center = touchLoc;
        }       
    }       
}

@end
```

This is then all glued together:

```
scrollView = [[JM_UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];   
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;     

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"berg.jpg"];
imageView = [[JM_UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 230)];
imageView.image = image;
imageView.center = CGPointMake(200,300);
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];

[scrollView addSubview: imageView];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(140,230);

scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.2;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.1;

[window addSubview: scrollView];
// Override point for customization after application launch
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

**The problem:**

When I start the application, I can move the UIImageView just fine and fluently. I can zoom-in and still be able to move it around.

However, it seems that whenever I zoom back out to the maximum level I seem then unable to move the UIImageView around anymore. It will jump at times, but by a maximum of 10 pixels. Use of NSLog() shows the touchesBegan/touchesMoved methods on the JM_UIImageView are no longer called.

Does anyone have any idea on what I might be missing here?

**EDIT**:

Would also accept an answer for wether or not this is the only way of implementing pinch-zooming with the zoombounce animation.

Comment: Any chance you could put up a link to a working xcode project where we can reproduce the bug?

Comment: Yes, but it might be a few hours as I'm at work right now :)

Comment: Tyler, the code is available from http://www.mathieukooiman.nl/scrollproblem.tgz (it is slightly different from the code above, but has the same problem). 

It seems the problem only ever occurs if the zoomBounce animation is done for when you try to zoom it beyond maximumZoomScale.